# How can Azure Data Factory access a Custom Data Connector

Tags: powerbi, azure-data-factory, connector

I've just started to look at Azure Data Factory as a possible way to get data we are currently consuming for Power BI via custom connectors, primarily to access Graph APIs. I can't see if the same data is available to Azure Data Factory. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I would be interested in your current setup with Power BI and custom connectors.  Can you give a bit more detail, maybe a picture?  Non-sensitive of course : )

Comment: Could do, but unsure what aspect interests you ...

Comment: Thanks very much for list below

Comment: Feel free to upvote or mark as answer if it’s been useful to you?

Comment: We're checking it out and will do when done … tks again

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Factory has a number of different features which may help:

- [Web activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) - call REST APIs from ADF pipeline; can only access public URLs
- [Webhook activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-webhook-activity) - call endpoints and pass callback URL
- [Azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity) - run Azure functions in the pipeline; functions are very flexible so could probably do this
- [Custom activity via Azure Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity) - run .net via Azure Batch; very customisable
- Databricks notebook - call a notebook written in Scala, Python, R, Java or SparkSQL - completely customisable

Alternately look at [Power BI Data Flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-dataflows-overview) which offers self-service ETL but remember the destination for your "L" is only really Azure Data Lake Gen 2 and Power BI Datasets.

Answer (score 0):

We decided to use Logic Apps, rather than Data Factory, which offer a convenient means to access Graph APIs, as Logic Apps support OAuth well i.e. we're not using Data Connectors any more

In addition, we put some of the more complicated logic into Stored Procedures, as Logic Apps, despite their name, can only handle basic logic